# Size of radical of $(n+1)\cdots(n+k)$ compared to $n$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Define
$$
g_k(n)=\frac{\log\left(\operatorname{rad}\left(\prod_{i=1}^kn+i\right)\right)}{\log n}
$$
and
$$
f(k)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}g(n,k)
$$
where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the largest squarefree number dividing $n$. What is known about the behavior of $f$? Is the value of $f(k)$ known for any $k>1$? Of course $f(1)=0$. Is $f(k)>k-1$ for some $k$?

Since $\gcd(n+1,n+2)=1$, $f(2)$ should be relatively simple to analyze, but even here I can't find its value. Note that $f(2)<1$ is consistent with (though certainly not implied by!) Pillai's conjecture that
$$
\liminf_{a,b>1,\ m^a\ne n^b}|m^a-n^b|=+\infty.
$$

Some modestly large examples of $n$ with $g_2(n)<0.95$ include
$$2^{11}5\cdot257\cdot26317 - 1 = 3^{12}19^4 - 2$$
$$2^{29}3^419\cdot87211 - 1 = 17^215790321^2 - 2.$$